# in MongoDB how do I update a list of key/value pairs c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

In MongoDB, accessing from C# driver:

I want to keep a list of keys (ints are fine), that have a current value.  (`Dictionary<int,int>`) works well for the concept)

I need to have multiple (10+) machines setting values in this Document. Multiple threads on each machine.

Using C# and the MongoDB driver I need to:

If the key exists, increment the value for that key.
If it does not exist, I need to Add it, and set the value to 1.

Critically Important:
    It can't overwrite values others are writing (I.E. No get doc and call Save() to save it)
    It has to handle adding values that don't already exist gracefully.

I *might* be able to have a query that inserts a new document with all of the keys set to values of 0 - if this would help, but it won't be easy, so that is not a preferred answer.

I've tried using a Dictionary, and can't seem to figure out how to update it without it creating:

```
null,
{ v=1}
```

On my insert (which doesn't include the k=, and has the null, that I don't want. and causes deserialization to blow)

I don't care what method of serialization is used for the dictionary, and am open to any other method of storage.

Any ideas?

My best guess so far is to keep a list of keys that is separate from the values (two List and append the key to the key list if it isn't found, requery the list and use the first one as the index in the 2nd list.  (This seems like it might have concurrency issues that could be hard to track down.)

I would prefer the Linq syntax, but am open to using the .Set (string,value) syntax if that makes things work.

Comment: This question is a bit all over the place which makes it hard to follow.  You simply want to update or append values to a dictionary?

Comment: I need to update the value if it exists, and add a new one if it does not.   And it has to handle updates from multiple machines at once.  And those machines could be updating the same key, or adding a key, or a different key